# Cannot install react-navigation

Tags: react-native, npm, react-navigation

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 While running the following command :

> npm install --save react-navigation

I'm getting following error:

> ```
> npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none was installed.
> npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none was installed.
> npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none was installed.
> npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none was installed.
> npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none was installed.
> ```

Has anybody solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are just WARN. They show up if you do OR if you don't have the required peer.
It's more of an informational thing to say hey make sure you install these too.

I thought they were errors as well when I started using npm a couple months back.